# What is the difference between x86 and x64

Tags: java

What is the difference between [x86 and x64 binaries here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html), we would like to download binaries for Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit options)

Comment: For 32-bit operating system you need x86. **x86 and x64 are terms used by Microsoft for 32-bit and 64-bit Operating Systems**

Comment: If you are going to install 64 bit `JDK` on your system then do install a 32 bit `JRE` atleast or else your browser's will not detect `JRE` as they are 32-bit programs.. By browser i mean `Chrome/Firefox`.. ;)

Comment: I would seriously consider using a 64-bit OS unless you have 2 GB or less, in which case I would seriously consider getting more memory. It doesn't cost that much these days.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

x86 is for a 32-bit OS, and x64 is for a 64-bit OS

Comment: how counter-intuitive that is!

Comment: Yes - in the real world, x86 CPUs include 16 bit chips like 8086 and 80286 as well as 32 bit CPUs from the 80386 and '486 onwards. There are no x64 processors in the series, i.e. ending in the characters "64". Trust Microsoft to get is so wrong. Probably the same mentality that motivated them to store 64 bit DLLs in \System32 and 32 bit DLLs in \SysWow64 folders. Typical MS small-mindedness. What do you expect when "micro" means very small, and "soft" means, well, soft. MS = Very small and soft.  ha ha ha

Comment: x stands for xD

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that Java binaries compiled as x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) applications respectively.

On a 64-bit Windows you can use either version, since x86 will run in WOW64 mode. On a 32-bit Windows you should use only x86 obviously.

For a Linux you should select appropriate type x86 for 32-bit OS, and x64 for 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 7):

x86 is a 32 bit instruction set, x86_64 is a 64 bit instruction set... the difference is simple architecture. in case of windows os you better use the x86/32bit version for compatibility issues. in case of Linux you will not be able to use a 64 bit s/w if the os does not have the long mode flag.

Whatever I recommend if you have a windows 7 32 bit OS then go for 32bit or x86 binaries and as for Ubuntu 12.04 use command `uname -a` or `grep lm /proc/cpuinfo` (*`grep lm /proc/cpuinfo` does not return value for 32 bit as 32 bit os does not has the cpuinfo flag*) to know the architecture OS your OS then use the binaries according to your OS.

** Note. Remember you can always install 64 bit os in 32 bit system as long as it supports enhanced 64 bit.. 64 bit os works better some times for multi purpose work and also supports more ram than 32bits. also you can install 32bit s/w in 64 bit os..

** OS = Operating system.

Comment: Joe asked for difference between Java binaries for these two architectures. Are you sore that you answered on that questions?

Answer (score 3):

### x86

- x86 is 32-bit instruction.
- 32-bit processor cannot have 64-bit version of an OS installed.
- It emerged from intel 8086 processor
- Only 4GB addressable memory limit.
- It can be accessed only for 2 cores.
- Less flexible and less secure
- Amount of virtual memory is less
- X86 Applications are compatible with both x86 and x64 systems.
- X86 having an architectural interface used by intel Require using more
  registers to split and store the value.

### x64

- x64 is 64-bit instruction.
- Many 32-bit programs work with 64-bit processors and OS.
- It came as an extension to x86 by AMD
- Maximum 8TB (As of 2018).
- It allows computers to access up to either 8 to 12 cores.
- Efficient and secure.
- Amount of virtual memory is larger.
- Compiling for x64 gives an advantage in speed only in 64bit OS.
- X64 has an architectural interface used by AMD.
- Values are larger than can be stored.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for posting a helpful answer. You can make it even better by linking to the source of the information.

Answer (score 2):

[x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) is a **family of backward-compatible instruction set architectures** based on the Intel 8086 CPU and its Intel 8088 variant.

An [instruction set architecture (ISA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) is an abstract model of a computer. It is also referred to as architecture or computer architecture.

A realization of an ISA is called an implementation. An ISA permits multiple implementations that may vary in performance, physical size, and monetary cost (among other things); because the ISA serves as the interface between software and hardware.

Software that has been written for an ISA can run on different implementations of the same ISA (Exp: 32bit or 64bit). This has enabled binary compatibility between different generations of computers to be easily achieved, and the development of computer families.

Both of these developments have helped to lower the cost of computers and to increase their applicability. For these reasons, the ISA is one of the most important abstractions in computing today.

Answer (score 1):

If you download Java Development Kit(JDK) then there is a difference as it contains native libraries which differ for different architectures:

- x86 is for 32-bit OS
- x64 is for 64-bit OS

In addition you can use 32-bit JDK(x86) on 64-bit OS. But you can not use 64-bit JDK on 32-bit OS.

At the same time you can run compiled Java classes on any JVM. It does not matter whether it 32 or 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough it was an Intel thing not a Microsoft thing.  X86 referred to the Intel CPU series from the 8086 to the 80486. The Pentium series still use the same addressing system. The x64 refers to the I64 addressing system that Intel came out with later for the 64-bit CPUs. So Windows was just following Intel's architecture naming.

Answer (score 1):

x64 is a generic name for the 64-bit extensions to Intel's and AMD's 32-bit x86 instruction set architecture (ISA). AMD introduced the first version of x64, initially called x86-64 and later renamed AMD64. Intel named their implementation IA-32e and then EMT64.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to memory usage, x86 is limited to circa 3 / 3,5 Gb, while x64 works fine with 4 Gb and more.

Moreover, when it comes to Windows, x86 will run on both X86 and x64 processors, while x64 requires x64 processor only.

Answer (score 0):

"When programming with C# you don’t usually need to worry about the underlying target platform. There are however a few cases when the Application and OS architecture can affect program logic, change functionality and cause unexpected exceptions."

"It is common misconception that selecting a specific target will result in the compiler generating platform specific code. This is not the case and instead it simply sets a flag in the assembly’s CLR header. This information can be easily extracted, and modified, using Microsoft’s CoreFlags tool"

https://medium.com/@trapdoorlabs/c-target-platforms-x64-vs-x86-vs-anycpu-5f0c3be6c9e2